# Azure alert not triggered when number of running pods drop set value

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-alerts

I have an Azure alert set up as follows:

- Signal: Pod Count
- Dimension: Kubernetes namesapce, phase
- Aggregation: Minimum pods less than 10
- Alert group: Selected to send an email

Please refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

However, even when I have 9 pods in `Running` phase and 1 in `CrashLoopBackOff` state, the alert is not triggered whereas I am expecting it to trigger. Any help would be grealy appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the same and got the results as expected.

As a first step, I created an AKS cluster and deployed 10 pods. All 10 pods are in a running state.

[image]

Next, I have created alert *Number of pods by phase* rule as below.

[image]

This alert rule will trigger if at least 10 pods are not in a running state.

Now, to test this logic, I will make a few of the pods are unavailable.
[image]

Please find below screenshot of the alert rule triggered email notification for unavailability of pods.

[image]

[image]

In above screenshot **Metric value** is the number of pods available in running state at the time of this alert has fired.